# Set theoretic issues in the definition of k-space or final topology wrt a proper class of functions

Tags: general-topology, set-theory

In Ronald Brown's [Topology and Groupoids](https://groupoids.org.uk/topgpds.html) ([pdf here](https://groupoids.org.uk/pdffiles/topgrpds-e.pdf)), section 5.9, p. 182, a topological space $X$ is called a **k-space** if the topology on $X$ coincides with the final topology with respect to all continuous maps $f: C\to X$ for all compact Hausdorff spaces $C$.

The collection of all such spaces $C$ and maps $f$ is not a set, but a proper class.  So it may seem difficult at first to define k-spaces in this way.  But then Proposition 5.9.1 shows that one can in fact choose a *set* of such spaces $C$ and functions $f$ to achieve the same thing.  I had some issues with the proof, so I'll ask about it in the slightly more general setting of final topologies with respect to a proper class of functions.

Suppose $X$ is a set and we have a (well-defined in ZFC) proper class $\mathcal{F}$ of functions $f:Y\to X$ where each $Y$ is a topological space.  (ZFC does not formally have the notion of class, but a well defined class just corresponds to some first order formula in ZFC.  That is the case for all compact Hausdorff spaces for example.)
We want to define the **final topology $\tau_{\mathcal F}$ on $X$ with respect to $\mathcal{F}$**.  It should be the finest topology that makes all these maps continuous.  Equivalently, a set $U$ in $X$ will be open iff $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $Y$ for all $f:Y\to X$ in $\mathcal{F}$.

> **Result:** There is a *set* $\mathcal{G}$ of elements of $\mathcal{F}$ such that the final topology on $X$ with respect to $\mathcal{G}$ is the same as $\tau_{\mathcal F}$.

The proof (paraphrased from Brown's 5.9.1) goes like this.  For each set $U\subseteq X$ that is *not* open in $\tau_{\mathcal F}$ choose some $f_U:Y_U\to X$ in $\mathcal{F}$ such that $f_U^{-1}(U)$ is not open in $Y_U$.  There is a *set* of such $U$ and the collection $\mathcal{G}$ of the $f_U$ is also a set and has the required property.

---

But does this really work in ZFC?  AC only works when starting with a set of sets, and there is no such thing as the [axiom of global choice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_global_choice) in ZFC.  I thought we could salvage the argument of choosing the $Y_U$ and $f_U$ like this.  We only care about spaces up to homeomorphism, and each set can be well ordered.  So we can assume each $Y_U$ will be an ordinal.  And by well ordering of ordinals, we can assume $Y_U$ will be the least ordinal that works for $U$.  All this is expressible by a first order formula in ZFC.  So now we have a *set* of ordinals and a set of all possible topologies for each of these ordinals and a set of continuous functions between these topological spaces and $X$.  So finally we can apply regular AC.

Does that work, or is there an alternative approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, there is no issue at all defining the final topology with respect to a class of functions in ZFC.  A class is not a set, but you can still write a formula that says what it means for something to be an element of the class, so you can quantify over elements of the class.  So there is no problem at all defining the set of $U\subseteq X$ such that $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $Y$ for all $f:Y\to X$ in $\mathcal{F}$; this is just a completely ordinary application of the axiom schema of Separation.

That said, your proposed argument does work to find a subset of $\mathcal{F}$ that determines the same final topology.  In fact, the use of AC can be avoided by using [Scott's trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scott%27s_trick).  Namely, for each $U$ that is not open, take the least ordinal $\alpha_U$ such that there is an element of $\mathcal{F}\cap V_{\alpha_U}$ which witnesses that $U$ is not open.  Then, let $\beta=\sup_U \alpha_U$ and take $\mathcal{G}=\mathcal{F}\cap V_\beta$.

Comment: Thanks! "ordinary application of the axiom schema of Separation": very good, and obvious in hindsight.  Also really useful second paragraph.